# Form-data posts when testing Postman backend API's - Node / Sequelize / Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postman

I am trying to test my backend API's with Postman and I keep getting either constraint errors (because of Sequelize) or in this case an error saying I am trying to insert "invalid input syntax for type integer" for the tect location line of my code. Both my model for this API and postgres have the respective field set as TEXT however it still gives me this error on Postman form-data for the first field.

As I have a file to insert I have to do this by the form-data method as I know how to do this the 'raw' way no problem. Is this is common error when dealing with Postman form-data? My form has text, ints and a file

Is this a problem to do with the way my data is parsed? I've seen formidable used before on tutorials, I'm already using Multer for storing my file away in the route and the API is saving the URL to Postgres (in theory).

[image: ![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51PZQ.png]

```
exports.createDiveSpot = async (req, res) => {

    const fileNameWithExtension = `${req.file.filename}-${req.file.originalname}`
    const newPath = `./assets/diveSpot/${fileNameWithExtension}`

    fs.rename(req.file.path, newPath, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(500)
        }
        diveSpot.create({
            diveLocation: req.body.diveLocation,
            diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
            diveSpotTypeID: req.body.diveLocation,
            diveSpotDescription: req.body.diveSpotDescription,
            photos: fileNameWithExtension,
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while creating the post.',
            })
          })
```

routes

```
//  create dive spot
    app.post('/api/divespot/createdivespot', upload.single("photos"), controller.createDiveSpot);
```

model schema

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const diveSpot = sequelize.define("diveSpots", {

            diveSpotID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                allowNull: false
            },
            diveLocation: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            diveRegionID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            diveSpotTypeID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            diveSpotDescription: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            photos: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            }},
        {
            timestamps: false
        }, {});
        diveSpot.associate = function(models){
            diveSpot.diveRegionID.belongsTo(models.diveRegion, {foreignKey: 'diveRegionID', as: 'diveRegionID'})
            diveSpot.diveSpotTypeID.belongsTo(models.diveType, {foreignKey: 'diveTypeID', as: 'diveTypeID'})
        };
    return diveSpot;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the stack error

Comment: That should be it added now.

Comment: Okay. Could you also show the postman body when sending ? My guess you are messing something with postman

Comment: That is the body of the postman post added now.

Comment: Let's look at the schema diveLocation